# Accessing and Assigning TMP_Text on Start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently using the Inspector to assign each text element but I would like to assign them through code instead in my start method.

How do I find the component by name because I have more than one.
I need each component to match up with the variables I have created.

````
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TMP_Text p1Name;
    public TMP_Text p2Name;
    public TMP_Text p1Score;
    public TMP_Text p2Score;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab them by name use the line

`GameObject.Find("NameHere")`

Then grab the component you need

```
TMP_Text yourText = null;

private void Start()
{
      yourText = GameObject.Find("nameHere").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
}
```

If all of your text objects are childed to the same parent, you can also iterate over the transforms of the parent instead of the larger `Find` and use `Transform.Find`. Is there a reason you don't want to assign them in the inspector though? Assigning a reference instead of finding them in `Start` is faster.

Comment: Thank you, I have been stumped for years on how to avoid the inspector. This was the right answer.

Comment: @SlurpeeSauce Anytime! If my post answered your question you can accept it to close the question and let others know there is a working solution.